# Javascript photo gallery -- viewing the full image

Tags: javascript, html

I have built a gallery in a Flask application. For loading purposes, the webpage loads thumbnail images. I am trying to use Javascript to allow the user to click on a thumbnail and see the full image. The issue that I am having is that the javascript seems only to work for the first instance of `<div id="image_con"></div>`. How can I get the function to work for all instances of the div? Or is that even possible with the way that I have things set up?

**HTML:**

```html
{% block content %}
{% for x in names %}
<div class="date_con">
    <h2>{{ x }}</h2>
    {% for y in names[x] %}
    <div class="event_con">
        <span class="event_data">{{ y['date_parsed'] }}</span>
        <span class="event_data">{{ y['title'] }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="image_con" id="image_con">
        {% for w in y['thumbs'] %}
        <img class="image_small" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='thumbnails/' + w + '')}}" alt="{{ y['id'] }}">
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="cover" id="{{ y['id'] }}">

        {% for z in y['fulls'] %}
        <img class="image_big" id="{{ z }}" style="display: none;" onclick="EventHandler(this.id)"
            src="{{ url_for('static', filename='gallery/' + z + '')}}" alt="error">
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var hit = false,
image_small = document.getElementById('image_con'),
active = null;

image_small.onclick = function (e) {
    var i = 0, tgt = e.target, items;
    if (tgt === this) return;
    items = children(image_small);
    var id = tgt.getAttribute('alt');
    console.log(id);
    while (tgt.parentNode !== this) tgt = tgt.parentNode;
    while (items[i] !== tgt) i++;
    // activate the image
    var tar = document.getElementById(id).children;
    tar[i].style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    output('index : ' + i);
    // helpers
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
    document.getElementsByClassName('cover')[0].style.display = 'flex';
};

function children(el) {
    var i = 0, children = [], child;
    while (child = el.childNodes[i++]) {
        if (child.nodeType === 1) children.push(child);
    }
    return children;
};

function output(s) {
    console.log(s);
};

function EventHandler(e) {
    console.log('id = ' + e);
    document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'auto';
    document.getElementsByClassName('cover')[0].style.display = 'none';
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the filename as the `id` for each image and was able to use a much simpler Javascript function.

***HTML***:

```html
{% block content %}
{% for x in names %}
<div class="date_con">
    <h2>{{ x }}</h2>
    {% for y in names[x] %}
    <div class="event_con">
        <span class="event_data">{{ y['date_parsed'] }}</span>
        <span class="event_data">{{ y['title'] }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="image_con" id="image_con">
        {% for w, z in zip(y['thumbs'], y['fulls']) %}
        <img class="image_small" id="{{ w }}" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='thumbnails/' + w + '')}}"
            alt="{{ y['id'] }}" onclick="viewLarger(tar='{{ z }}target', this.id)">
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="cover" id="{{ y['id'] }}"></div>
    {% for z in y['fulls'] %}
    <center>
        <img class="image_big ui_img_material" id="{{ z }}target" style="display: none;" onclick="EventHandler(this.id)"
            src="{{ url_for('static', filename='gallery/' + z + '')}}" alt="error">
    </center>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

***Javascript***:

```js
    function viewLarger(tar, e) {
        document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'block'
        document.getElementById(tar).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
        document.getElementsByClassName('cover')[0].style.display = 'flex';

    };

    function EventHandler(e) {
        document.getElementById(e).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'auto';
        document.getElementsByClassName('cover')[0].style.display = 'none';
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you have a listener for every image, try adding a listener to the parent, `image_con` instead of each image.

```
document.getElementById('image_con').addEventListener('click', event => {
    const { target } = event;
    if (target.classList.contains('image_small')) {
        /**
         * the rest of the click handler goes here
         */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to this.

> Unlike some other element-lookup methods such as Document.querySelector() and Document.querySelectorAll(), getElementById() is only available as a method of the global document object, and ***not available as a method on all element objects in the DOM***. 
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Usage_notes

---

So, I recommend you use className instead of ID.
For example,

```
document.querySelectorAll('.image_con').forEach(function(item){
  item.onclick = function(e){
    /* Your codes here... */
  }
})
```